# Does Singularity have anything similar to a Docker network?

Tags: docker, singularity-container

In Docker, I can create a private network:

```
docker network create my-net
```

run a MySQL database in one container:

```
docker run -d --rm --name mysql-server --network my-net -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=secret mysql/mysql-server:latest
```

and communicate between that database and my application using the created network:

```
docker run -it --rm --network my-net my_app
```

All three calls reference the same "my-net", along which communications occur. Now, I need to run this using Singularity, rather than Docker. There is no mention of a network option in the Singularity Users Guide, nor does there appear to be any information about it that I can find. Can Singularity do something similar and, if so, how?

Naively, I tried to replace 'docker' with 'singularity'

```
docker network create my-net
```

but found that Singularity does not have such a direct replacement. I need to run this code an HPC environment where I do not have access to "root".

Comment: Have you read https://sylabs.io/guides/3.0/user-guide/networking.html ? There doesn't seem to be a drop-in replacement, but the same behavior is possible.

Comment: Thanks @jakub. I had not seen that information and it does look like what I want, but I need to run this in an HPC environment where I do not have access to root and the user's guide says, "These options can only be used by root." Apologies for not noting that in the original post; I have edited that post to include this information.

Comment: In addition the answer below, I recommend checking out the section in the docs comparing Singularity and Docker functionality if you haven't already. Some things can be drop in replacements, others can take a little tweaking. https://sylabs.io/guides/3.7/user-guide/singularity_and_docker.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments above, [Singularity does have virtual network capabilities](https://sylabs.io/guides/3.7/user-guide/networking.html) but they generally involve root permissions for at least the initial set up.

However, if all you want is to communicate between containers you don't need to do anything special for that. By default, your singularity containers have the same network access as if run on the host OS directly. Similarly, the ports used by the singularity container are accessed using the hostname of the host server. In Docker terms, you can think of it as if `EXPOSE` is always run on ports used in the container.

If you need distinct, virtual networks however, you'll probably need to work with your cluster admins.

So, if you have a mysql and app container running on the same node, the app need only use `localhost:3306` for the database url. If it's running on another node, use the hostname of that instead of localhost. It goes both ways though. So if your singularity container tries to start `sshd` internally on the default port, it will fail because the host `sshd` is already using that port.